# Is true namespacing possible with Polymer?

Tags: polymer

Is real namespacing (like the ones used in C#/Java) possible with Polymer at the moment?

Something like:
[image]

If not, where would be the best locations to communicate with the team and know their thoughts about it?

Comment: It is required to have a `-` in your components' names according to the spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#concepts

Comment: While the below answer is correct, you are writing custom elements. I might suppose that you could write a custom namespace element...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespacing is not really supported in HTML. Here's a quote from [the WHATWG FAQ](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#Will_there_be_support_for_namespaces_in_HTML.3F) on it:

> However, unlike the XHTML serialization, there is no real namespace syntax available in the HTML serialization

The topic has come up a number of times but, at least to my knowledge, there are no immediate plans to implement namespacing. In the future it may be possible to access the element registry to create aliases, but that's also just conjecture on my part.

If you'd like to discuss it the best place is probably [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/polymer-dev).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link, checking out the mailing list.

Something i also though was.. As it's possible to declare polymer-elements inside of another, if it would be possible to turn that element private and only accessible to the parent... so if i have a component named `my-component-awesome` and inside a `header`, that `header` would only be available for `my-component-awesome`

Comment: Not sure if I follow what you mean when you say "declare polymer-elements inside of another." If you mean using an instance of an element inside of another element's Shadow DOM, then yes, that will keep in encapsulated. However, there's only 1 custom element registry (it's global) so any custom elements you register will be available for instantiation anywhere in the document.